# Assembly error - instruction expected while writing a string

Tags: assembly, nasm, shellcode

While writing the simplest assembly for shellcode i wrote this code

```
BITS 64
global _start
section .data
_start:
  ;ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
  ;rax = 1

jmp poziv

vracajse:
xor rsi,rsi
pop rsi
xor rax,rax
mov al,1 ; were calling write
;The parameters are in rdi, rsi, rdx, r10, r8, r9. in that order
xor rdi,rdi ;
xor rcx,rcx ; need low 8 bytes dont want null in machine code
mov cl,1
mov edi,ecx ; edi =1 writing to stdout
xor rdx,rdx
mov dl,15 ; were writing 15 chars
syscall

poziv:
call vracajse

poruka:
.ascii "Pozdrav svete!\n"
```

and got the following error

```
writing_2nd_try.nasm:28: error: parser: instruction expected
```

Why is is telling me that my code poruka:
.ascii "Some string" is not a valid instruction (label and a message) but if i write it as db then its okay.

(Also interesting to me is if i write .section data instead section .data i get the following errors

```
writing_2nd_try.nasm:3: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
writing_2nd_try.nasm:3: error: parser: instruction expected
```

)

Im kinda new to all this, but i thought i knew what i was doing.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, pastebin sites are frowned upon here, as the content is only temporarily available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is is telling me that my code `poruka: .ascii "Some string"` is not a valid instruction (label and a message) but if i write it as `db` then its okay.

The syntax and directives differs between assemblers. `.ascii` is a directive recognized by the GNU assembler, but with NASM you use `db` (declare byte) instead, as you've already discovered.

> (Also interesting to me is if i write .section data instead section .data i get the following errors

Because `section` is a directive recognized by NASM, and `.section` is not. So NASM thinks that you're declaring a local label named `section` (label names starting with a period are considered local in NASM syntax). So NASM sees a local label named `section` followed by the word `data`, which makes no sense.

Comment: Besides using `db`, Nasm will allow you to enclose the string in single quotes, double quotes, or "back quotes" (the character we use here to indicate `code`). Back quotes, but not the other two, will allow Nasm to recognize "\n" and other C-ish escape sequences. Otherwise you're just going to see "\n" as text.